# Fragement reference from another activity returns null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I start a details fragment in a new Activity when in portrait mode like so....

```
fDetail=(HistoryOFragDetail) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        if(fDetail!=null&& fDetail.isVisible())
        {
            fDetail.changeData(st);

        }else{ // portrait 

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HistoryOActFrag.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", st);


            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

while in portrait mode I load the fragment like so...

```
public class HistoryOActFrag extends SherlockFragmentActivity...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.history_actifrag_layout);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String myIndex = intent.getStringExtra("index");

    HistoryOFragDetail f2 = (HistoryOFragDetail)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    f2.changeData(myIndex);



}
```

the layout is as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.myFragTesting.OIn.HistoryOFragDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem...

Every time I try to get a reference to the fragment in the activity I just came from I get an  NPE. The code additions that fail is below.

```
public class HistoryOActFrag extends SherlockFragmentActivity...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.history_actifrag_layout);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String myIndex = intent.getStringExtra("index");

HistoryOFragDetail f2 = (HistoryOFragDetail)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
f2.changeData(myIndex);


/// ..................new step here ....
    HistoryOFragMaster f1 = (HistoryOFragMaster )getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
    Log.d("myLog","......f1 = "+f1");  ////   = NULL ???? Why can't I do this ?



}
```

When in Landscape I keep my fragments in one Activity and reference work fine.

I realize that fragment1 is in the Activity I just came from can I not get a reference when my fragments are in two separate Activities ?  Better yet what is correct way to get a reference to f1 ?

-Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

While an activity is running you can add a fragment to its layout using these 4 steps.

1. Get a refrence to the Fragment Manager
2. Begin a Fragment Transaction
3. Add the fragment
4. Commit the fragment transaction

   ```
   FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
           .beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.title_fragment_container,
           new TitlesFragment());
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
   ```

Make sure you are using the commit.

Comment: what if you are adding fragments using xml layouts only ?

Comment: title_fragment_container in the above code is a fragment saved in xml Layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you've started new activity, all fragments asociated with previous activity (in your case f1) are not available in current activity. The fastest solution which cames to my mind is to transfer via intent more parameters which are needed in details activity in portrait mode.